# Marketing Cloud SMS Tracking

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect

I would like to track SMS deliverability but SFMC does not have good support for SMS like it does for Email.

**I see two options for SMS**

1. **SMS Message Detail Report**: This will not help much as we need to manually generate the report and import.
2. **Undeliverable SMS view**: I can query and automate it but it only indicates undeliverables.

Both those options does not help me much; Can you give me some insight if there are any other options?

Answer (score 1):

You obviously can't track if the user opened your SMS message. You can't even make sure he received it. When [using the API to send the message](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postMessageContactSend.htm), Salesforce's web server returns a token which [you can use to check if the message was delivered](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/getMessageContactDelivery.htm) though.

Unfortunately I don't see an endpoint to query this delivery status, or to get the token generated when sending the messages (this would allow to query the results). So I think your best bet would be the second option.

If, after a couple of hours, the message was not marked as undeliverable, then I'd consider it delivered. You can't be 100% sure, but after this time, it should be almost guaranteed that it was delivered.